# flatten Vs flatMap with def method and val function

Tags: scala, flatten, flatmap

**flatten Vs flatMap with def method and val function:**

I defined a def method called **toInt**:

```
  def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    try {
      Some(Integer.parseInt(s.trim))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  }
```

And this method works fine with both flatten and flatMap as follows:

```
//using toInt method
val x = 1.to(5).toList
val y = List("a")
val z = x ++ y
val q = z.map(_.toString)

//using map and flatten
println(q.map(toInt).flatten)
//using flatMap
println(q.flatMap(toInt))
```

Now I defined the same toInt functionality(as in def method) using val in a function "tooInt":

```
val tooInt: String => Option[Int] = s => {
  try {
    Some(Integer.parseInt(s.trim))
  } catch {
    case c: Exception => None
  }
}
```

This works fine with flatten but **NOT** with flatMap as shown below:

```
//using map and flatten
 println(q.map(tooInt).flatten)
 //using flatMap // this has error
 **println(q.flatMap(tooInt))**
```

Could you please help me in understanding this?

Best Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to help the compiler a little with expansion to make this work:

```
q.flatMap(s => tooInt(s))
```

It all boils down to the fact that we have an implicit `option2Iterable` defined in `Option.scala`. When you first `map` and then `flatten`, the `Option[Int]` is already in scope and the implicit can be applied. But when you `flatMap`, the compiler has to first expand `tooInt` to `s => tooInt(s)` and then apply the implicit resolution, but that doesn't work. Why doesn't it work? because the compiler looks for an implicit of type:

```
pt=(=> String => Option[Int]) => (String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?])
```

Which doesn't exist. On the contrary, the `toInt` method is first expanded into a function type, and then the implicit is searched for `Option[Int]`:

```
-- toInt : pt=String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value r in X)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- { ((s: String) => toInt(s)) } : pt=String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value r in X)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ((s: String) => toInt(s)) : pt=String => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value r in X)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- (s: String)Option[Int] : pt=scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] EXPRmode (site: value $anonfun in X)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- s : pt=String BYVALmode-EXPRmode (site: value $anonfun in X)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> String
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    [search #3] start `(s: String)Option[Int]`, searching for adaptation to pt=Option[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] (silent: value $anonfun in X) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    [search #3] considering scala.this.Option.option2Iterable
```

We can also see it in the decompiled code:

```
val r: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = q.flatMap[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]]({
    {
      final <artifact> def $anonfun$main(s: String): Iterable[Int] = scala.this.Option.option2Iterable[Int](toInt(s));
      ((s: String) => $anonfun$main(s))
    }
  }, immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Int]());
```

Comment: even q.flatMap(tooInt(_)) would work. I guess the question is about why methods can be passed to flatMap and function literals can't.